# Problem displaying adaptive website layout with Bootstrap for low resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I would like to make an adaptive design for a small website with Bootstrap, but I'm a newbie and can't find any solution for my problem here. I want to be able to display the header for a wide set of different devices, it means for cell phones with small display too. So I have written something like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=0.5">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <header class="bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row p-3 bg-success rounded">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-left">
                <img src="images/home.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Home">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 text-center">
                <h2>MainText</h2>
            </div>    
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 text-right">
                <img src="images/settings.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Settings">
            </div>          
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It works with every web-browser pretty good, but it doesn't work properly for small resolutions.
This is the normal view of this page:

[image: Normal resolution]

But after reaching some width (it should be 576px as I see), it breaks my layout into three lines for every div:

[image: Lower resolution]

It doesn't depend on text or image size, there a lot of place there, so it should be a behavior of the Bootstrap.

How could I avoid it and do a really adaptive design? My page is very simple and it should be a solution to display it properly, I can't understand why Bootstrap doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add col for smaller screens. You can remove col-sm and leave only col-
This happen to your code because you didnt set anything for smaller screen than sm and bootstrap by default set any column to col-12. So your three rows on small screens had col-12 inside them. The title went to center cause of text-center class and last image went left cause of text-right.

```
<header class="bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row p-3 bg-success rounded">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3 text-left">
            <img src="images/home.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Home">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-6 text-center">
            <h2>MainText</h2>
        </div>    
        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-3 text-right">
            <img src="images/settings.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Settings">
        </div>          
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Live [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aqk2ez0u/)

If you want different approach on small screens change the col-* classes.
col-xs-* have been dropped in Bootstrap 4 in favor of col-*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it really works now! But may I ask you one question more regarding it? I have try col-xs-3 instead of col-3 before and it didn't work. What is the reason of this difference?

Comment: My fault, col-xs-* have been dropped in Bootstrap 4 in favor of col-*.Can you please upvote the answer and tick as answer?You can read here some things about media queries and breakpoint on booststrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/